# Xamarin Forms WebView Swipe

Tags: c#, webview, xamarin.forms, swipe-gesture

I have a simple app with 2 views(View A and View B).On click of button I navigate to the second view(View B).View B contains a webview i.e the entire content page is occupied by the webview. There is a requirement by the client where if the user swipes from left to right on the webview the app should navigate back to the first view(View A).I tried adding Xamarin Forms swipe gestures but it is not working.How can I detect swipe in a webview.
Please help!!!

Comment: Try to call View A using these events, webview.OnNavigated and webview.OnNavigating.

Comment: @WasifMahmoodMustafa The user should navigate back to View A only on Swipe.

Comment: Did you solve this?